# Why does Martin Luther King use the word "flesh" in his speech?

Tags: meaning, martin-luther-king

What is the significance and the intention of King using the word "flesh" halfway through his speech?

> and the glory of the Lord shall be revealed, and all **flesh** shall see it together

Is it related to the main theme of the speech concerning segregation and injustice or am I missing the point here? From research, I also realized it's a verse from the Bible.

Comment: What do dictionaries have to say about this particular way in which 'flesh' is used? [eg [M-W sense 4a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flesh)] As in the expanded term 'flesh and blood'?  (A deeper debate about the distinction between spirit and flesh belongs on Christianity.SE).

Comment: King was a minister, and this is a biblical quotation. He used the word "flesh" because the word appeared in the passage he was quoting in the Bible, at least in some translations. If you want to know what the word means in that Bible passage, you should probably ask in the Biblical Hermeneutics Stackexchange.

Comment: As to *why* King chose that verse, I can only speculate that it was for oratorial reasons. It was a powerful way to make a point that under the skin, we are all the same. Any other way could be open to denial.

Comment: In such a context, "flesh" would usually be understood to mean "humanity".

Answer (score 3):

Martin Luther King (MLK) was a seminary graduate and used biblical imagery and allusions prolifically in his civil rights speeches—as you probably already know. In any case, as you are also probably aware, the phrase from Isaiah 40:5 and is used in the context of his famous “I Have a Dream” speech: “And the glory of the LORD shall be revealed, and all flesh shall see it together: for the mouth of the LORD hath spoken it.”  The word ‘flesh’ in this context is translated from the Hebrew בָּשָׂר (*basar*) meaning, not surprisingly, flesh of humans or animals (Davidson 123). So, I don’t think a simple etymology offers any particularly keen or deeper insight into MLK’s “I Have a Dream” speech.  It is just an archaic way of saying humankind (and you can include animals for even more purchase). Rhetorically, archaic language is sometimes used to add authoritative register to a speech enhancing a speaker’s *ethos*.  Even John F. Kennedy used it occasionally; but not as richly as MLK. On another note, King is using the phrase as messianic imagery, recognizing that, ultimately, it probably will not be until the return of Christ that peace will be restored upon the earth. So, this is essentially the meaning in context of the 1963 speech given in Washington, D.C. But knowing King, he chose these words deliberately and there is more to be seen here.

To unpack it further you want to examine the usage of the word in its *sitzimleben* (“setting in life”)—that is to say the biblical/historical context. Here you have a rich discussion which might add deeper meaning to the context of MLK’s speech. Since the phrase is from Isaiah 40:5, this is our biblical/historical context and we ask, “What do these words mean in the context of Isaiah?”  Isaiah was arguably the most prolific prophet of Israel—his book being the longest among the prophetical books of the Old Testament divided into 66 chapters. He wrote at a time when Israel was nearing its demise—being decimated by the Assyrians and Babylonians respectively. Isaiah himself was eventually taken captive by the Babylonians. Much of his book is a call to repentance so Israel would not be wiped-out by her enemies. After many chapters of chastising Israel for its sin, finally, in chapter 40  Isaiah begins offering some consolation prophesying eventual deliverance from exile and peace at some future date. Scholars would say this portion of scripture is especially messianic in nature. Of course, MLK would have known this. King is looking to the future—looking to better times. I might be taking some liberties here, but it is striking to note that “all flesh” has a potent register to it when considering the context of the civil rights movement—it is, arguably, about flesh—black and white, as it were. The notion of “all flesh” means we are all in this together which resonates in the historical context of the book of Isaiah (see Young 3: 31) and the civil rights movement of the 1960’s. We might be different colors, but still people of the same “flesh”—as such, we need to celebrate our common humanity—and realize the “true meaning of [our] creed . . .’that all men are created equal.’”

Sources:

Davidson, Benjamin. *The Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*. Henrickson Publishers, 1981.

*The Holy Bible*, (King James Version). Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1972.

Young, Edward J. *The Book of Isaiah* (3 Volumes). Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Company, Grand Rapids, 1981.

Comment: 'flesh'  בשר also means 'tidings. The deeper understanding would be that not only are we all of one flesh, but in the end we are the embodiment of the good news of God, accomplished by him drawing us together as one people.

Comment: I wouldn't deem to add to this comprehensive answer but it's possible to over-emphasise the context of the term's use. "Flesh" was a direct quote from the KJV bible, and as a Christian MLK would be keen to replicate his quotes exactly. Of more relevance therefore is what the *Bible* means by the word. It is used very frequently, especially by Jesus, with reference to mankind. I don't think the meaning of "meat", and therefore the allusion of "dead meat", can be avoided. Why does Jesus call mankind "meat"? Especially evident today, I think it's because a lot of people are the walking dead.

Answer (score 0):

All "flesh" is all "human beings."

The reference is that "and the glory of the Lord shall be revealed, and all flesh shall see it together."

Only humans are capable of understanding the glory of the Lord. And when it is revealed, "everyone" will see it together.